# Ошибка unity 3d: Error building Player

Tags: unity3d, error404

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building
>   Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
>   [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в скрипте игрока, проверь все.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у Вас в скрипте `Player` используется пространство имен `UnityEditor`.

А это пространство имен и все его классы и методы доступны **только в редакторе**. Поэтому, что бы не было ошибок при сборке проекта, подключение пространства имен и все использования его классов необходимо "обернуть" директивами препроцессора

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```